# Pass boolean var into a router-outlet

Tags: angular

I have this code:

App.component.ts

```
 public euskera: boolean;

ngOnInit(): void {

    this.euskera=false;
  }

  setEuskera(){
    this.euskera=true;
  }
  setCastellano(){
    this.euskera=false;
  }
```

Wanna pass euskera's value to a child in a router outlet:

app.component.html

```
  <div id="content">
    <router-outlet [euskera]="euskera">
    </router-outlet>

  </div>
```

home.component.ts

```
  public title: string
  public title_eus: string;
  @Input() euskera:boolean=false;
```

home.component.html

```
<div *ngIf="euskera">
  <h1>{{title_eus}}</h1>
</div>

<div *ngIf="!euskera">
  <h1>{{title}}</h1>
</div>
```

How can I pass the value of the variable through the router-outlet to get it from all my components and have the IFs do the matching?

Answer (score 0):

You could try using angular localization

https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-implement-localization-in-angular-using-i18n-tools-a88898b1a0d0/

Edit:
Or call different components...